# Configure enum constants on its own line using Eclipse Code Formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-jdt, spotless

I'm using [Spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle) with Gradle. I've [configured](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle#eclipse-jdt) it to use Eclipse's JDT Code Formatter:

```
spotless {
  groovyGradle {
    greclipse("4.21.0").configFile("${rootDir}/config/spotless/eclipe_groovy_formatter.xml")
  }
  java {
    eclipse("4.21.0").configFile("${rootDir}/config/spotless/eclipe_jdt_formatter.xml")
    endWithNewline()
    importOrder("", "javax", "java")
    indentWithSpaces(2)
    lineEndings(LineEnding.UNIX)
    removeUnusedImports()
    trimTrailingWhitespace()
  }
}
```

The content of `eclipe_jdt_formatter.xml` is just:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<profiles version="12">
  <profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="Fulgore Team" version="12">
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_selector_in_method_invocation" value="80" />
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.insert_new_line_for_parameter" value="false" />
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.line_length" value="100" />
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert" />
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert" />
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The problem is that I would like to configure the correct setting(s) within the (Eclipse) XML file in order to have the `enum` values each on its own line.

For instance, this is how it's currently formatting the source code:

```java
public enum Type {
  VALUE, OTHER, ANOTHER,
}
```

...but I would like:

```java
public enum Type {
  VALUE,
  OTHER,
  ANOTHER,
}
```

If anyone knows the combination of settings I can use within the XML file to accomplish this I would really appreciate it. I've tried a couple of combinations from `.formatter` and/or `.indent` without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_enum_constants" value="49"/>`

Comment: It's going to be nearly impossible for me to realize how did you know that `49` was the right value for making `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_enum_constants` to work in such way :/